# Get all both values and keys from dictionary only once

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this :

```
my_dictionary = { a:['b','c','d']
                  b:['c','d']
                  c:[]
                  e:['a']
                 }
```

`where a,b,c,d,e are files`

Let this dictionary be a list of dependencies, such way that if I modify something the file that is the key, I'll have to recompile all the files in my .values().

So, in example: if I modify something in file `e` I'll have to recompile file `a` (because `e` depends on `a`), then `b`, `c`,`d`(because `a` depends on `b`,`c`,`d`), but even though `b` depends on both `c` and `d`, I won't add them to my `recompiling_list` because I already added them when I was at `a`.

I've try to go recursively, but I always end up in an infinit loop.

Is there any way I cand create a list like described above? The order is really not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (not tested):

```
def finddep(depdict, fil, depset):
    if fil in depset:
        return
    depset.add(fil)
    for dep in depdict[fil]:
        filddep(depdict, dep, depset)

depset = set()
finddep(my_dictionary, 'e', depset)
```

Use set for optimization (`O(1)` membership test). You can actually use list or other collection types.

Answer (score 0):

You run into an infinit loop when your dependencies form a circle.
You could use the recursive algorithm and just stop when you added all files that exist.
To avoid duplicated elements use a set. A set allows each element only one time.
You can also easily transform the set to a list after the calculation

Comment: I did not know about sets. I'll be looking into them right now.